# Oracle - ORA-02270 : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have this two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1 (
  DATERIF DATE NOT NULL,
  DOMAINCODE VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  DATACODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  DSDATO VARCHAR2(50),
  CDDWH CHAR(1),
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBL1 PRIMARY KEY (DATERIF, DOMAINCODE, DATACODE)
)
;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE TBL2 (
  DATERIF DATE NOT NULL,
  PRODUCTCODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  PRODCATEG VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PRODUCTDESCR VARCHAR2(100),
  PRODUCTTYPE VARCHAR2(10),
  CODSECTION  VARCHAR2(10),
  CDDWH CHAR(1 BYTE),
  DTUPDATED DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBL2 PRIMARY KEY (DATERIF, PRODUCTCODE, PRODCATEG),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TBL2_TBL1_PRODUCTTYPE FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTTYPE) REFERENCES TBL1(DATACODE),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TBL2_TBL1_CODSECTION FOREIGN KEY (CODSECTION) REFERENCES TBL1(DATACODE)
)
;
```

on the Table TBL2 creation, I get ORA-02270 : no matching unique or primary key for this column-list error
Sincerely, I can't solve the problem. Could someone help me? Thank you

TT

Comment: Obviously there is an error but could you tell your intention behind the foreign key?

Comment: This is what I wanted to ask, too. Maybe it helps, if you explain the tables. TBL2 looks like a product table, but the product code is not the primary key. Instead you allow the same product code for different products as long as they are in different categories (PRODCATEG) and in different DATERIFs. What is a DATERIF? And what does TBL1 represent? Why can a DATACODE be both a PRODUCTTYPE or a CODSECTION (your attempted foreign keys)? This looks strange. I have the bad feeling that you may really want a very different data model from what you currently have.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner, It looks like the primary keys are having different purpose and I am not sure about both foreign keys but anyhow just considering the error provide the answer which is open for OP to clarify.

Comment: This is exactly the case: primary keys have a different purpose because TBL1 is a domain table: PRODUCTTYPE  can be for exple: 'motorcycle','cars' ,CODSECTION can be '4 trokes' or '2 trokes' ... and both 'motorcycle' and '4 trokes' must be in TBL1.DATACODE if I want to save in TBL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:Clarification required from OP***

The problem you are facing is because of the restriction on `foreign key` aka `referential integrity`,

As the official doc says, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)

**Foreign Key Constraints**

> A foreign key constraint (also called a referential integrity constraint) designates a column as the foreign key and establishes a relationship between that foreign key and a specified primary or unique key, called the referenced key. A composite foreign key designates a combination of columns as the foreign key.

Having assumption that both the `primary key` we see in your code has different purpose and you want to have value in `PRODUCTTYPE` and `CODESECTION` column to be checked against value in `DATACODE` as to fulfill some integrity, you need to create an `unique` constraint on the `DATACODE` column and then the `foreign key` reference to it,

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1 (
  DATERIF DATE NOT NULL,
  DOMAINCODE VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  DATACODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  DSDATO VARCHAR2(50),
  CDDWH CHAR(1),
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBL1 PRIMARY KEY (DATERIF, DOMAINCODE, DATACODE),
  CONSTRAINT UK_DATACODE_TBL1 UNIQUE(DATACODE)
);

CREATE TABLE TBL2 (
  DATERIF DATE NOT NULL,
  PRODUCTCODE CHAR(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  PRODCATEG VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PRODUCTDESCR VARCHAR2(100),
  PRODUCTTYPE VARCHAR2(10),
  CODSECTION  VARCHAR2(10),
  CDDWH CHAR(1 BYTE),
  DTUPDATED DATE,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBL2 PRIMARY KEY (DATERIF, PRODUCTCODE, PRODCATEG),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TBL2_TBL1_PRODUCTTYPE FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTTYPE) REFERENCES TBL1(DATACODE),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TBL2_TBL1_CODSECTION FOREIGN KEY (CODSECTION) REFERENCES TBL1(DATACODE)
);
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- `TBL1`'s primary key is on `DATERIF, DOMAINCODE, DATACODE`
- if you want to reference `TBL1` from `TBL2`, `TBL2`'s foreign key constraint **must** match those columns (not in names, but in datatypes and order)
- currently, you're referencing it only by the `DATACODE` column (see those two `FK`s)

How to fix it?

- you can't because `TBL2` doesn't contain `DOMAINCODE` column (though, it does contain `DATERIF` and `DATACODE`, but that's not enough)
- you could, if you

  - added `DOMAINCODE` to `TBL2`, or
  - change `TBL1`'s primary key to e.g. `DATERIF, DATACODE` only
  - replace current primary key to something else (e.g. a sequence number)